# Adding partners to calendar in Odoo

Tags: calendar, odoo, openerp-8

I need to create an event to the user's calendar in Odoo v.9 but it is not creating the attendees.

```
event={
    'start':start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    'stop':end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    'duration':hours,
    'allday':False,
    'partner_ids': [emp.employee_id.id],
    'name': myshift.account_id.name,
    'user_id': emp.employee_id.user_id.id,
  }
event=self.env['calendar.event'].create(event)
```

The collection partner_ids is a Many2Many relationship with res.partner, which is the way to write the partner id in calendar.event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant create values in a many2many field just giving it the id (this is only for many2one). 
If the field is a one2many or many2many:

```
(0, 0, { values }) link to a new record that needs to be created with the given values dictionary
(1, ID, { values }) update the linked record with id = ID (write values on it)
(2, ID) remove and delete the linked record with id = ID (calls unlink on ID, that will delete the object completely, and the link to it as well)
(3, ID) cut the link to the linked record with id = ID (delete the relationship between the two objects but does not delete the target object itself)
(4, ID) link to existing record with id = ID (adds a relationship)
(5) unlink all (like using (3,ID) for all linked records)
(6, 0, [IDs]) replace the list of linked IDs (like using (5) then (4,ID) for each ID in the list of IDs)
```

So, what you should add is instead of a list, [(4, emp.employee_id.id)]

Comment: Thanks, I arrived to that but the id is in other model. Now it works: 'partner_ids': [(4,[emp.employee_id.user_id.partner_id.id])]

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that works

```
'partner_ids': [(4,[emp.employee_id.user_id.partner_id.id])],
```